# Preview button display data on database not just updated

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a form divided on for pages every page when the user click next I save my data on my database until the 4th page when he click validate it save the data on the forth page.
I have created a button preview on the last page (preview all data from the 4 pages)

When the user want update the form on the last page, when he click preview the data are not saved yet how can I display the data just entred and not saved yet (even I tried to saved them on the prevew action but the same problem)?

**The forth page(too long just ) of the form when the button preview exist :**

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="autresDistinctions" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label">Persons</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        {{ form_widget(form.persons, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>

………..

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">

        <a href="{{ path('admin_Serv_ preview ') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Preview</button></a>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right">Validate</button>

    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**Page preview :**

```
<div class="blog-header">
    <h1 class="blog-title">Preview </h1>
</div>
<div class="row">

div class="container fluid custom-locale-form">


    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nom" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label">Adrese</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            <span style="display:inline-block; width:500px;padding:5px">{{ ser.form.adress }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nom" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            <span style="display:inline-block; width:300px;padding:5px">{{ ser.form.phone }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="nom" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label">F</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        <span style="display:inline-block; width:300px;padding:5px">{{ ser.form.fax }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="nom" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3  form-control-label">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        <span style="display:inline-block; width:300px;padding:5px">{{ ser.form.email }}</span>
    </div>
</div>

……………………………………

</div>
</div>
```

**Preview action :**

```
public function previewAction(Request $request)
{
    $ser = new Serv() :
    $forma = $ser->getFormulaire();
    $form = $this->createForm('StoreBundle\Form\FormPerType',$ forma);

    if(!$ser){
        return $this->redirectToRoute('Admin_ser_per');
    }

    $form ->handleRequest($request);


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();




    return $this->render('AdminBundle:Serv:preview.html.twig', array(
        ‘ser’=> $ser,
        'form'   => $form->createView()

    ));
}
```

Comment: Store the information in session and retrieve it when user revisits the page. Remove the session data once the user data has been saved in DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways -

1. Store the data in the cookies
2. Store the data in temp table in the database and when you click on the preview button fetch the data and populate the preview.